# Как сделать глобальный хук на нажатие клавиш в расширении Visual Studio 2022, vsix?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, hook, visual-studio-2022, visual-studio-extensions

Хочу сделать глобальный хук на нажатия клавиш в расширении Visual Studio. Попробовал разные вариации WinAPI+USER32, через aeyrwn. `SetWindowsHookEx()`. Но ничего не работает. Я знал что для этого хука нужно окно, например, в консольном приложении он работать не будет. Но студия же имеет окно, почему тогда в ней не работает?

Подскажите, реально во обще реализовать "Глобальный" хук на клавиатуру, или максимум что возможно это через обычный `KeyProcessorProvider` хукать текстовый редактор студии?

Вот код который я пробовал:

```
internal class WinAPIKeyboardHook
{
    private const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
    private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
    private const int WM_SYSKEYDOWN = 0x0104;
    private const int WM_KEYUP = 0x101;
    private const int WM_SYSKEYUP = 0x105;

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, LowLevelKeyboardProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod,
        uint dwThreadId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

    public delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    public event EventHandler<Keys> OnKeyPressed;
    public event EventHandler<Keys> OnKeyUnpressed;

    private LowLevelKeyboardProc _proc;
    private IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;

    public WinAPIKeyboardHook()
    {
        _proc = HookCallback;
    }

    public void HookKeyboard()
    {
        _hookID = SetHook(_proc);
    }

    public void UnHookKeyboard()
    {
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);
    }

    private IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelKeyboardProc proc)
    {
        using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
        using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
        {
            return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, proc, GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);
        }
    }

    private IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN || wParam == (IntPtr)WM_SYSKEYDOWN)
        {
            int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);

            OnKeyPressed.Invoke(this, ((Keys)vkCode));
        }
        else if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYUP || wParam == (IntPtr)WM_SYSKEYUP)
        {
            int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);

            OnKeyUnpressed.Invoke(this, ((Keys)vkCode));
        }

        return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }
}


// Using 

WinAPIKeyboardHook kbh = new WinAPIKeyboardHook();
kbh.OnKeyPressed += OnKeyPressed;
kbh.OnKeyUnpressed += OnKeyPressed;
kbh.HookKeyboard();

void OnKeyPressed(object sender, Keys e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Key Pressed: " + e.ToString());
}
```